Save files from local path into Excel and export the jpgs with a specific file name
I need to gather 1,000s of jpg images from a local folder and save them in another folder with a specific file name found in a column of an Excel sheet.
Code to find and insert the images into cells.
Sub InsertImagesToFitToCell()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim imgFolder As String
    Dim imgDict As Object
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim imgPath As String
    Dim pic As Picture
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim imgWidth As Double
    Dim imgHeight As Double
    Dim ratio As Double
    Dim newWidth As Double
    Dim newHeight As Double
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to insert the images
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw data") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    ' Set the folder path where images are located
    imgFolder = "Y:\Marketing\Marketing Storage\CatalogImagesCorpByDiv\Ag catalog img\" ' Change to your image folder path
    
    ' Initialize dictionary to store image file paths
    Set imgDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in Column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column A
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts from row 2, change if needed
        fileName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        ' Construct full image path
        imgPath = imgFolder & fileName
        
        ' Check if the image file exists
        If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then
            ' Insert the image
            Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(imgPath)
            
            ' Set the target cell where you want to fit the image
            Set targetCell = ws.Cells(i, 2) ' Adjust column index as needed
            
            ' Calculate the original dimensions of the image
            imgWidth = pic.Width
            imgHeight = pic.Height
            
            ' Calculate the ratio of image dimensions
            ratio = imgWidth / imgHeight
            
            ' Calculate new dimensions to fit the cell
            If ratio > targetCell.Width / targetCell.Height Then
                ' Fit based on width
                newWidth = targetCell.Width
                newHeight = newWidth / ratio
            Else
                ' Fit based on height
                newHeight = targetCell.Height
                newWidth = newHeight * ratio
            End If
            
            ' Resize the picture
            pic.Width = newWidth
            pic.Height = newHeight
            
            ' Position the image to fit the target cell
            pic.Top = targetCell.Top + (targetCell.Height - pic.Height) / 2
            pic.Left = targetCell.Left + (targetCell.Width - pic.Width) / 2
            
            ' Add the image path and picture object to dictionary
            imgDict.Add imgPath, pic
            
        Else
            ' Notify if image file not found
            MsgBox "Image file '" & fileName & "' not found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clean up
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set imgDict = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Images have been inserted and sized to cells!", vbInformation

End Sub

Code to save images with the file name from column B.
Sub SavePic()
On Error Resume Next
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ActiveShape As Shape
Trow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Trow - 1
ActiveSheet.Sharps(i).Select
Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)
picname = Cells(i + 1, 2)
'Create a temporary chart object (same size as shape)
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Width:=ActiveShape.Width, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Height:=ActiveShape.Height)
'Format temporary chart to have a transparent background
cht.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
cht.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
'Copy/Paste Shape inside temporary chart
ActiveShape.Copy
cht.Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
'Save chart to User's Desktop as PNG File
cht.Chart.Export ("C:\Users\bpolivka\Desktop\Book7_files\" & picname & ".jpg")
'Delete temporary Chart
cht.Delete
Next i
End Sub

When the images are saved into the folder they are too small to see and it doesn't save the actual image, it's a white jpg.
Is there a way to increase the file size and save the image instead of a white box, or a simpler way to do this?

What happens if you comment out that On Error Resume Next ?

Also ActiveSheet.Sharps(i).Select  ?    After adding a chart, what do you think becomes the ActiveShape  ?

Are the original images JPEGs? if yes, you could copy and rename them.

Are the original images JPEGs? if yes, you could copy and rename them. Yes they are jpgs. DO you mean just copy them from one folder to a new folder and rename them? That won't work for 10,000 images i would need to rename.

Unless you need to resize the images you can do something like FileCopy "C:\Temp\file1.jpg" "C:Temp2\newName.jpg" which copies and renames the file.

I found this code which seems to work. But it distorts the images when saved into the folder. Ideally the images would be 600px x 600 px but they need to be scaled to that size proportionately. How would I change it so that happens? the second part is how can the code be written to skip over any images that aren't found? currently if one isn't found in the folder a pop up appears and I have to click ok for it to keep running.
